# Recognizing Regular Languages in Layman terms

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, regular-languages, finite-automata

I understand that regular languages are languages which can be computed by Finite Automata however i am having some trouble understanding how one can identify a regular from non-regular.

I know that `0*1*` is regular because the machine just needs to make sure the 0s and 1s are in order

I know that `0^n 1^n`is non regular because the machine needs to keep count to make sure there is an equal number of 0s and 1s

But why is `(01)^n` considered regular? Doesn't the machine have to keep track to make sure that there are `n` amount of `01`?

How about `{0^m 1^n | n>m}`?

What is the general rule for quickly figuring out if something is regular or not in layman terms?

Comment: Why would you expect that there is a "quick" general rule. The only general rule is to apply the definition of a regular language or one of the several statements equivalent to it. In general, knowing whether some arbitrary set theoretic expression corresponds to a regular language can be arbitrarily complicated, e.g. $\{0\mid RH\}\cup\{0^n1^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\land \neg RH\}$ where $RH$ stands for the Riemann Hypothesis is regular if $RH$ is provable and not if it's refutable.

Comment: You don't need to count anything to decide $\{(01)^n\ |\ n\geq 0\}$, all you need is to remember whether the last symbol you saw was a $0$ or a $1$. Remembering $n$ is not needed to check whether the next symbol is OK.

Comment: With practice such simple examples will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

the way to test if something is non regular is to use the pumping lemma for regular languages. It can prove that a language is non regular, but it will not necessarily prove that a language is regular. To prove that some language is regular, you can create a finite automata for that language.

Comment: You can’t prove that a language is regular using the pumping lemma, since not all languages satisfying its conditions are regular.